# PHP save file without save as dialog

Tags: php, content-type, savefiledialog

I'm creating MS Office Word document with PHP as following:

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=filename.doc");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
```

But I need to save file to the server without save as dialog to be able to do something with the created `*.doc` file and give it to user only after the modification.

So how can I acheive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you use is for sending as download to the browser user.
To save on the server, use the this in PHP :

```
file_put_contents('path/to/ms/word/document.doc', $theData);
```

Then after you use your code to sent the saved file.

Comment: God, that's soo easy... and I'm even confused. You made my day)